# How to remove duplicate CSS styles from a string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I have a string containing CSS though a lot of it has duplicated styles.

`.button:hover {background: #fff} p.test {font-size: 11px} .button:hover {background: #fff} .button:hover {background: #fff}...`

How could I go about removing duplicated CSS styles from that string so the example above would become:

`.button:hover {background: #fff} p.test {font-size: 11px}`

All of the styles are located in the `<style></style>` tag and I am getting the string with **jQuery** by using `$("style").html()`

Comment: You don't need to. The browser does it automatically for you (CSSOM is the optimized result of all your currently applying CSS) and it's what actually applies to your DOM. The chances you could do it better, faster and with less resources than the browser are basically `null`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Is there a way this could be done through JavaScript though? The string of CSS itself has to not contain duplicates

Comment: Why? *The browser will do exactly what you want automatically.* To do what you want in general is a *very* complicated thing.

Comment: There is, but I don't think it can be done easily without risk of changing its end result. For example: if you have `#one .button {styles}` and `#two .button {styles}` you need a script that understands removing the `.button {styles}` part after `#two` would be wrong and it's a false duplicate of the same string after `#one`, and it would alter the outcome of your CSS. 
It has to be done by a script that is capable of understanding CSS selectors, at least up to a point.

Comment: Or compare selectors *per-se* (and also ignore spacing), do the same for styles. What if you have more than one declaration? Should it break them up and compare one by one? What if you have similar selectors? Like `.stuff`,  `[class="stuff"]` and `[class*="stuff"]`? If your declarations are sometimes ended in `;` and other times not... Point being: you need a pretty smart script. An exceptional coder might work on this script for weeks and still not get it right. How long is it going to take you? Your question, at best, is far too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP asked if it could be done and specified (as I read it) the removal of duplicate rules. A simplistic approach:

- Split by rule end `}`
- Trim off white space and re-attach delimiter
- Filter out duplicates
- Join into string

```js
var style = ".button:hover {background: #fff} p.test {font-size: 11px} .button:hover {background: #fff} .button:hover {background: #fff} #one .button {color: #000} #two .button {color: #000}";

var uniqueRules = style
  .split('}')
  .map(function(rule) {
    return rule ? rule.trim() + '}' : '';
  })
  .filter(function(rule, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(rule) === index;
  })
  .join(' ');

console.log(uniqueRules);
```

**Using the CSSOM (CSS Object Model)**

Taken directly from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList#Get_all_CSS_rules_for_the_document_using_Array_methods

I added this because someone falsely claims "The browser does it automatically for you (CSSOM is the optimized result of all your currently applying CSS)". Notice the duplicated style `.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; }`. Really nice optimization there. Maybe the criticizer would like to post an answer explaining how he could have possibly been mistaken?

```js
var allCSS = 
    [].slice.call(document.styleSheets)
        .reduce(function (prev, styleSheet) {
            if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
                return prev +
                    [].slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules)
                        .reduce(function (prev, cssRule) {
                            return prev + cssRule.cssText;
                        }, '');
            } else {
                return prev;
            }
        }, '');
        
console.log(allCSS);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {position: fixed;}
.as-console-wrapper {position: fixed;}
```

The CSSOM does do a few things for us though. It will normalize (not to be confused with optimize) the rules allowing us to find the **exact duplicates** without worrying about white space, missing semicolons and the like.

```js
var allCSS = 
    [].slice.call(document.styleSheets)
        .reduce(function (prev, styleSheet) {
            if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
                return prev +
                    [].slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules)
                        .reduce(function (prev, cssRule) {
                            return prev + cssRule.cssText;
                        }, '');
            } else {
                return prev;
            }
        }, '');
        
var uniqueRules = allCSS
  .split('}')
  .map(function(rule) {
    return rule ? rule.trim() + '}' : '';
  })
  .filter(function(rule, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(rule) === index;
  })
  .join(' ');
  
console.log(uniqueRules);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {position: fixed;}
.as-console-wrapper {position: fixed}
.as-console-wrapper {position:fixed;}
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
}
.as-console-wrapper 
{
position: fixed;
}
```